# Increase build number without generating new subfolder when publish

Tags: c#, build, installation, publish, oneclick

Can I increase the build number without generating a new subfolder for each new build number, when I publish a project?

I use the oneclick installer and it generates the `Application Files\Project Build.Number` subfolder.

I only want to increase the internal build number but **not** generate a new subfolder for each release under `Application Files\<build-version>\**`, instead I want `Application Files\<static-version>\**`

Is that possible, I tried to this in the assembly, but it didn't worked:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
```

But this still generate new subfolders, each time I publish.